# ActiveWorkbook vs ThisWorkbook table count issue

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have an issue with my vba addin in excel 2016 on Mac OS. My function which counts the number of rows in a table is not working properly.

In excel 2011 it works fine, displaying the correct count of `122`. However in excel 2016 I get `subscript out of range` error. When I change to `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook` I get `67`.

I have tried using Sheets function instead of `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` and `ListObjects("ExternalData_1")` but neither works

Current code:

```
MsgBox (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_History").ListObjects(1).ListRows.Count)
```

I expect `122` rows but instead I am getting `67`

Comment: If `ThisWorkbook` is appropriate here then I wouldn't use `ActiveWorkbook` - which one should it be?

Comment: What do you get when you add a line `Msgbox ActiveWorkbook.Name` before that line?

Comment: @TimWilliams it was originally ActiveWorkbook but since I was strangely getting subscript out of range error, I switched to ThisWorkbook

Comment: @SiddharthRout when I added that line I got the correct name of the workbook I have opened.

Comment: where do you have your function? in a workbook or in the personal workbook? How do you call it? do you use it in a cell as a formula or do you simply call it in a sub in VBA?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook where the code is running - if this is an add-in then presumably you *wouldn't* want to use `ThisWorkbook`.  Alittle more detail about exactly what you're doing would be useful here.

Comment: @Ibo The function is in a sub which is in an addin running with the workbook.

Comment: @TimWilliams It is an addin I am using.  The function is in a sub which is in an addin. It’s suppose to give the total number of rows from a table (dataset) in another sheet called Data History which is within the same workbook.

In excel 2011, the code (Using Activeworkbook) runs fine and I get the correct count (122 rows). However in excel 2016, it gives the subscript out of range error. When I change ActiveWorkbook  to ThisWorkbook, I get a count of 67, but that count is incorrect.

Comment: Since an add-in is typically hidden, it's never the ActiveWorkbook, so it's unclear how this could have worked?

Comment: @JHousty22 so you have to use activeworkbook given if the workbook is active, to make sure of it, you need to create a button (use shapes and assign the sub to it) in the same sheet you have the table, use the name of the table instead of the index, there is no way if your code is correct that it returns a wrong number

Comment: @TimWilliams so apparently the ActiveWorkBook.Name outputs the correct name of the workbook but ThisWorkBook.Name outputs the name of the addin. I believe that is where the confusion is. However like I was mentioning I am getting subscript out of range when I use ActiveWorkbook in the sub to do the count.

Comment: @Ibo please see my comment above

Comment: Does `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_History").Name` give you an error?  If not, what does `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_History").ListObjects.Count` produce?

Comment: @TimWilliams no errors. The first gives me the correct name of the sheet and the second prints 0

Comment: @JHousty22 click on a cell in the table and see "Table Tools" menu pop up in the ribbon? If so, go to Design and on the most left side see the name of the table, can you see that? what is the name of your table? Right now, I guess what you have is just a format of a table and not the table itself

Comment: If you get 0 then there are no tables/listobjects on the "Data_History" sheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams solved it! There was no data on the sheet via the listobject. I decided to use the Range method which worked.  MsgBox (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_History").Range("TH_Table").Rows.Count). Thank you for the assist with this.

Comment: @Ibo please see my comment above and adding a better table name did help. Thank you for your perspectives on this.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

MsgBox (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_History").Range("TH_Table").Rows.Count).